# Como puedo incluir dos modelos en una única función de php

Tags: php, laravel, jwt, cuenta-usuario, registro

Estoy creando una **API REST Laravel**. en el proyecto hay dos tipos de usuarios: *usuario (user)* y *Vendedor (user2)*. He creado un controlador para cada usuario, ya que tienen distintos tipos de datos o funciones dentro del la web. el problema viene con la autenticación. He creado un *Helper JwtAuth* y en él esta el método de autenticación por token:

```
public function signup($email, $password, $getToken = null) {
    $user = User::where ([
        'email' => $email,
        'password' => $password
    ])->first();
```

Esta seria la función. como pueden ver `$user` utiliza el modelo *User*, pero yo necesito que también extraiga los datos del modelo *User2*. ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

De momento he creado un segundo *helper JwtAuthUser2* con las mismas funciones pero enfocado a user2.

En principio funciona bien, pero me da miedo que me traiga problemas en un futuro, *por ejemplo a la hora de conectar dos usuarios de distintas tablas entre sí*.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con _a la hora de conectar dos usuarios de distintas tablas entre sí_? Probablemente solo necesitas incluir un dato en la petición para saber qué tipo de usuario es el que debes validar.

Comment: hola. soy bastante nuevo en esto. te comento. en el proyecto se comunicaran a través de la web user y user2. Me traerá problemas el hecho de que cada tipo de usuario tenga un JwtAuth por separado?

Comment: A priori, no tiene porque generar problemas, pero, sin conocer el proyecto, no es posible dar una respuesta afirmativa, ni negativa. :-D

Comment: pero crees que debo unir los dos tipos de usuario bajo la misma función. Me refiero a que la Función utilice dos modelos a la vez para hacer la validación o voy por buen camino si he creado un Helper JwtAuth para cada tipo de usuario?

Comment: Creo que es mejor tenerlos por separado, para evitar dos consultas en caso de que el usuario no coincida con el primer tipo en que intentas autentificar.

Comment: vale. entonces dejo de romperme la cabeza con eso hehehe y lo dejo como lo tengo. a fin de cuentas tienes razón son dos tipos de usuario con distintos tratamientos y distintas tablas.

Comment: igualmente y perdona la insistencia. ¿Seria posible añadir el segundo modelo de usuario dos a la función?

Comment: Edita la pregunta para agregar el método que usas en la segunda tabla y cómo ejecutas los dos.

Comment: utilizo el mismo método pero en otro helper